# I deploy my project by ansible, I always get the error: ImportError: No module named zipfile

Tags: ansible

> fatal: [45.76.146.29]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true,
>   "module_stderr": "Shared connection to 45.76.146.29 closed.\r\n",
>   "module_stdout": "Traceback (most recent call last):\r\n  File
>   \"/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1507867975.52-212330775158986/apt.py\",
>   line 17, in \r\n    import zipfile\r\nImportError: No module
>   named zipfile\r\n", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE", "rc": 0}

what cause this error?

Comment: Can you edit your comment and post the playbook?

Answer (score 7):

You have some reduced installation of python on your system.
I've seen such error on old linux images at Vultr.

Try with `apt-get install sudo python-minimal python-setuptools`